# MySQL: Ignore insert if match two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a help with a PHP/MySQL issue. I have a table named `users` and other named `relationships`.

```
users
--------------
id (PK)
name
email
etc

relashionships
--------------
id (PK)
id_user (FK to users.id)
id_friend (FK to users.id)
rating
```

I'm trying to `INSERT` multiple relationships but I don't want duplicated entries. I want to ignore the current row if the row is duplicated. I can't use the `IGNORE` statement because the `id_user` and the `id_friend` columns aren't unique. A user/friend may have multiple relationship rows.

Any tip?

Comment: Is it good idea to create primary key on two columns(id_user,id_friend) columns for table relashionship, and id col of relashionship would be col having identity on.

Comment: PKs, FKs, and compound PKs...you should read about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique key on the id_user/id_friend tuple. Neither of them are unique, but their combination is.

See [multiple column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks amenadiel, I found that solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419459/mysql-insert-ignore-if-in-particular-row-values-in-two-columns-already-exists) and worked for me!

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX relation ON relationship (id_user, id_friend)
```